# copy a file to a volume of a running docker container using the remote API

Tags: docker

How do you copy a file to a volume of a running docker container using the remote API?

I know about docker cp (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) but I would like to do this using the remote API.

I would like to do the equivalent of

`docker cp path_to_local_file container:location_in_volume`

Except I want to POST the file using the remote API.

I can't find anything about it in the remote API docs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [PUT archive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/extract-an-archive-of-files-or-folders-to-a-directory-in-a-container):

```
PUT /containers/{container name or id}/archive?path={path in container} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-tar


{{ TAR STREAM }}
```

The body of the request should be a tar file.